# I have some overlapping troubles in my diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Why are my points in front of the lines? In my opinion i should  see the whole line but the line is interrupted by the points... How can i avoid this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar sampled,colorbar style={samples=12},
  view={0}{90}  % view the plot from the top
]
\addplot+[domain=-350:-100,no marks,green,very thick] {30};
\addplot3 coordinates {(-350,40,1e5) (-100,40,1e5)};
\addplot3+[ultra thick,yellow] coordinates {(-350,50,1e5) (-100,50,1e5)};
\addplot3+[
    scatter,mark=diamond*,only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{count},
    z buffer=sort  
]
table {
mean    range   count 
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
-220.2  198 200176
-224.4  196.8   200176
-220.8  192 200176
-221.4  190.8   50044
-226.2  176.4   200176
-199.2  156 50044
-201.6  153.6   50045
-219    147.6   50044
-252.6  133.2   50044
-210    129.6   200176
-250.8  127.2   50044
-201    126 50044
-229.2  124.8   50044
-183    123.6   200176
-168    122.4   200176
-275.4  118.8   200176
-172.2  114 50044
-219    109.2   250220
-217.8  104.4   50044
-226.8  103.2   200176
-224.4  103.2   50044
-217.2  100.8   50045
-220.2  99.6    200176
-222.6  94.8    50044
-225.6  93.6    200176
-246.6  92.4    200176
-220.8  81.6    50044
-253.8  75.6    200176
-224.4  74.4    50044
-234.6  70.8    200176
-207.6  69.6    200176
-201    68.4    200176
-200.4  67.2    200176
-183.6  67.2    200176
-204.6  63.6    200176
-197.4  63.6    200176
-246    62.4    200176
-201.6  62.4    50044
-195.6  62.4    200176
-244.8  60  50044
-218.4  57.6    250220
-214.8  57.6    200176
-207.6  57.6    50044
-247.8  56.4    200176
-233.4  56.4    200176
-201    56.4    50045
-169.8  56.4    100088
-240    55.2    200176
-207.6  55.2    200176
-204    55.2    250220
-168.6  54  50044
-142.2  54  200176
-243.6  52.8    200176
-244.2  51.6    50044
-172.2  51.6    50044
-169.8  51.6    100088
-247.2  50.4    50044
-277.8  49.2    200176
-273    49.2    200176
-239.4  49.2    200176
-225    49.2    50044
-222.6  49.2    250220
-226.8  48  250220
-211.2  48  450396
-238.2  46.8    200176
-210.6  46.8    200176
-237.6  45.6    200176
-207.6  45.6    200176
-202.8  45.6    200176
-245.4  44.4    200176
-168.6  44.4    100088
-166.2  44.4    50044
-225.6  43.2    200176
-240.6  42  200176
-178.2  42  200176
-181.2  40.8    200176
-239.4  39.6    250220
-220.2  39.6    250220
-174    36  200176
-172.8  36  50044
-251.4  34.8    200176
-243    34.8    50044
-173.4  34.8    200176
-224.4  33.6    250220
-207.6  33.6    200176
-186    33.6    200176
-171.6  33.6    100088
-235.8  32.4    200176
-183.6  31.2    200176
-273    30  200176
-223.8  30  200176
-214.2  30  50044
-230.4  28.8    50044
-229.2  28.8    50044
-219.6  28.8    250220
-174    28.8    200176
-279    27.6    200176
-277.8  27.6    200176
-229.8  27.6    200176
-207    27.6    200176
-301.2  26.4    200176
-277.2  26.4    200176
-274.8  26.4    200176
-255.6  26.4    200176
-224.4  26.4    50044
-222    26.4    50044
-257.4  25.2    200176
-237    25.2    500440
-233.4  25.2    250220
-228.6  25.2    50044
-221.4  25.2    200176
-179.4  25.2    100088
-161.4  25.2    100088
-255.6  24  200176
-229.2  24  200176
-225.6  24  6.00528e+006
-210    24  200176
-206.4  24  200176
-181.2  24  400352
-274.2  22.8    200176
-256.2  22.8    200176
-233.4  22.8    200176
-223.8  22.8    200176
-197.4  22.8    200176
-255.6  21.6    400352
-235.2  21.6    200176
-228    21.6    50044
-225.6  21.6    50044
-184.8  21.6    200176
-182.4  21.6    200176
-178.8  21.6    200176
-174    21.6    200176
-276.6  20.4    200176
-269.4  20.4    200176
-259.8  20.4    200176
-258.6  20.4    200176
-232.2  20.4    450396
-226.2  20.4    50044
-222.6  20.4    50044
-202.2  20.4    200176
-186.6  20.4    200176
-180.6  20.4    200176
-273.6  19.2    200176
-258    19.2    200176
-252    19.2    200176
-246    19.2    200176
-234    19.2    50044
-231.6  19.2    200176
-229.2  19.2    400352
-219.6  19.2    200176
-168    19.2    100088
-273    18  200176
-261    18  200176
-258.6  18  200176
-240.6  18  200176
-235.8  18  200176
-234.6  18  100088
-233.4  18  200176
-225    18  200176
-223.8  18  50044
-221.4  18  200176
-219    18  200176
-211.8  18  200176
-187.8  18  200176
-173.4  18  200176
-277.2  16.8    200176
-276    16.8    200176
-260.4  16.8    200176
-234    16.8    50044
-231.6  16.8    200176
-225.6  16.8    200176
-183.6  16.8    200176
-165.6  16.8    200176
-160.8  16.8    100088
-277.8  15.6    200176
-256.2  15.6    200176
-237    15.6    200176
-233.4  15.6    200176
-231    15.6    200176
-228.6  15.6    650572
-220.2  15.6    200176
-219    15.6    200176
-216.6  15.6    600528
-202.2  15.6    200176
-199.8  15.6    200176
-190.2  15.6    200176
-189    15.6    400352
-183    15.6    200176
-177    15.6    200176
-174.6  15.6    200176
-172.2  15.6    200176
-156.6  15.6    100088
-260.4  14.4    200176
-252    14.4    200176
-228    14.4    50044
-226.8  14.4    350308
-222    14.4    200176
-218.4  14.4    3.00264e+006
-213.6  14.4    400352
-190.8  14.4    200176
-189.6  14.4    400352
-183.6  14.4    200176
-177.6  14.4    200176
-165.6  14.4    100088
-151.2  14.4    200176
-279    13.2    200176
-276.6  13.2    200176
-275.4  13.2    200176
-261    13.2    400352
-259.8  13.2    200176
-258.6  13.2    200176
-257.4  13.2    200176
-238.2  13.2    200176
-235.8  13.2    200176
-222.6  13.2    450396
-217.8  13.2    200176
-208.2  13.2    200176
-199.8  13.2    200176
-193.8  13.2    200176
-192.6  13.2    200176
-185.4  13.2    200176
-179.4  13.2    200176
-291.6  12  200176
-262.8  12  200176
-261.6  12  400352
-260.4  12  600528
-258    12  200176
-256.8  12  200176
-244.8  12  200176
-241.2  12  400352
-240    12  200176
-226.8  12  200176
-219.6  12  50044
-217.2  12  400352
-189.6  12  200176
-182.4  12  100088
-181.2  12  400352
-169.2  12  100088
-279    10.8    200176
-276.6  10.8    400352
-268.2  10.8    400352
-264.6  10.8    200176
-261    10.8    200176
-257.4  10.8    200176
-256.2  10.8    200176
-231    10.8    3.05268e+006
-226.2  10.8    200176
-225    10.8    200176
-223.8  10.8    200176
-220.2  10.8    50044
-217.8  10.8    200176
-214.2  10.8    200176
-204.6  10.8    200176
-203.4  10.8    200176
-199.8  10.8    200176
-195    10.8    200176
-192.6  10.8    600528
-191.4  10.8    200176
-190.2  10.8    200176
-189    10.8    400352
-186.6  10.8    100088
-183    10.8    400352
-172.2  10.8    200176
-168.6  10.8    100088
-267.6  9.6 200176
-265.2  9.6 200176
-261.6  9.6 200176
-260.4  9.6 400352
-254.4  9.6 200176
-247.2  9.6 400352
-237.6  9.6 200176
-236.4  9.6 200176
-231.6  9.6 200176
-230.4  9.6 50044
-228    9.6 250220
-226.8  9.6 250220
-225.6  9.6 250220
-224.4  9.6 450396
-223.2  9.6 200176
-206.4  9.6 400352
-192    9.6 200176
-187.2  9.6 200176
-183.6  9.6 300264
-182.4  9.6 200176
-172.8  9.6 400352
-170.4  9.6 200176
-169.2  9.6 250220
-163.2  9.6 100088
-297    8.4 200176
-291    8.4 200176
-279    8.4 200176
-277.8  8.4 400352
-273    8.4 200176
-262.2  8.4 200176
-257.4  8.4 400352
-256.2  8.4 200176
-246.6  8.4 200176
-237    8.4 200176
-232.2  8.4 50044
-229.8  8.4 50044
-228.6  8.4 200176
-225    8.4 450396
-223.8  8.4 50044
-214.2  8.4 200176
-205.8  8.4 200176
-193.8  8.4 200176
-190.2  8.4 800704
-185.4  8.4 400352
-171    8.4 200176
-162.6  8.4 100088
-284.4  7.2 200176
-276    7.2 200176
-264    7.2 200176
-259.2  7.2 200176
-237.6  7.2 200176
-229.2  7.2 200176
-228    7.2 450396
-225.6  7.2 450396
-224.4  7.2 250220
-222    7.2 200176
-220.8  7.2 200176
-217.2  7.2 200176
-211.2  7.2 200176
-202.8  7.2 400352
-201.6  7.2 400352
-193.2  7.2 200176
-187.2  7.2 200176
-180    7.2 400352
-174    7.2 200176
-172.8  7.2 200176
-165.6  7.2 150132
-152.4  7.2 200176
-277.8  6   200176
-264.6  6   400352
-263.4  6   200176
-262.2  6   400352
-259.8  6   400352
-258.6  6   200176
-250.2  6   200176
-246.6  6   200176
-241.8  6   200176
-240.6  6   200176
-237    6   200176
-232.2  6   200176
-229.8  6   400352
-226.2  6   500440
-223.8  6   200176
-222.6  6   200176
-221.4  6   200176
-220.2  6   200176
-216.6  6   200176
-215.4  6   200176
-213    6   400352
-209.4  6   200176
-201    6   200176
-195    6   200176
-186.6  6   300264
-183    6   200176
-181.8  6   400352
-180.6  6   200176
-172.2  6   200176
-171    6   400352
-166.2  6   50044
-135    6   200176
-297.6  4.8 200176
-278.4  4.8 200176
-276    4.8 200176
-270    4.8 200176
-267.6  4.8 200176
-266.4  4.8 200176
-265.2  4.8 200176
-260.4  4.8 200176
-258    4.8 200176
-248.4  4.8 800704
-243.6  4.8 200176
-238.8  4.8 200176
-237.6  4.8 200176
-234    4.8 200176
-230.4  4.8 200176
-226.8  4.8 250220
-224.4  4.8 500440
-223.2  4.8 300264
-220.8  4.8 200176
-219.6  4.8 200176
-217.2  4.8 200176
-211.2  4.8 200176
-207.6  4.8 200176
-200.4  4.8 200176
-198    4.8 200176
-195.6  4.8 200176
-194.4  4.8 100088
-189.6  4.8 600528
-187.2  4.8 200176
-186    4.8 400352
-184.8  4.8 400352
-183.6  4.8 200176
-182.4  4.8 400352
-181.2  4.8 200176
-178.8  4.8 200176
-176.4  4.8 200176
-175.2  4.8 200176
-169.2  4.8 200176
-168    4.8 200176
-166.8  4.8 100088
-163.2  4.8 100088
-160.8  4.8 200176
-158.4  4.8 100088
-157.2  4.8 100088
-147.6  4.8 100088
-135.6  4.8 200176
-330.6  3.6 200176
-281.4  3.6 400352
-279    3.6 400352
-277.8  3.6 400352
-276.6  3.6 200176
-275.4  3.6 400352
-269.4  3.6 200176
-263.4  3.6 200176
-262.2  3.6 400352
-259.8  3.6 400352
-255    3.6 200176
-253.8  3.6 200176
-252.6  3.6 200176
-247.8  3.6 200176
-244.2  3.6 200176
-239.4  3.6 400352
-238.2  3.6 600528
-237    3.6 200176
-235.8  3.6 200176
-229.8  3.6 200176
-228.6  3.6 400352
-227.4  3.6 1.7015e+006
-226.2  3.6 600528
-225    3.6 200176
-223.8  3.6 450396
-222.6  3.6 200176
-220.2  3.6 400352
-219    3.6 200176
-216.6  3.6 400352
-215.4  3.6 600528
-213    3.6 200176
-209.4  3.6 400352
-208.2  3.6 200176
-205.8  3.6 200176
-199.8  3.6 200176
-198.6  3.6 200176
-196.2  3.6 200176
-195    3.6 500440
-192.6  3.6 200176
-191.4  3.6 200176
-187.8  3.6 200176
-186.6  3.6 400352
-185.4  3.6 300264
-183    3.6 400352
-180.6  3.6 200176
-177    3.6 200176
-172.2  3.6 400352
-171    3.6 200176
-168.6  3.6 200176
-162.6  3.6 100088
-161.4  3.6 200176
-157.8  3.6 200176
-155.4  3.6 200176
-309.6  2.4 200176
-301.2  2.4 200176
-291.6  2.4 400352
-289.2  2.4 200176
-280.8  2.4 200176
-279.6  2.4 400352
-278.4  2.4 200176
-276    2.4 200176
-272.4  2.4 200176
-271.2  2.4 200176
-267.6  2.4 400352
-262.8  2.4 200176
-260.4  2.4 200176
-258    2.4 400352
-256.8  2.4 200176
-253.2  2.4 600528
-249.6  2.4 200176
-248.4  2.4 200176
-247.2  2.4 200176
-243.6  2.4 200176
-242.4  2.4 200176
-241.2  2.4 400352
-240    2.4 200176
-237.6  2.4 400352
-236.4  2.4 400352
-232.8  2.4 3.00264e+006
-230.4  2.4 200176
-228    2.4 400352
-226.8  2.4 1.05092e+006
-225.6  2.4 400352
-224.4  2.4 600528
-223.2  2.4 200176
-222    2.4 200176
-220.8  2.4 200176
-219.6  2.4 200176
-218.4  2.4 400352
-213.6  2.4 200176
-211.2  2.4 200176
-208.8  2.4 800704
-200.4  2.4 200176
-196.8  2.4 200176
-195.6  2.4 200176
-192    2.4 200176
-190.8  2.4 400352
-189.6  2.4 600528
-188.4  2.4 600528
-187.2  2.4 400352
-186    2.4 700616
-183.6  2.4 200176
-181.2  2.4 300264
-180    2.4 400352
-177.6  2.4 200176
-175.2  2.4 400352
-171.6  2.4 300264
-170.4  2.4 200176
-166.8  2.4 200176
-164.4  2.4 400352
-162    2.4 100088
-160.8  2.4 200176
-158.4  2.4 400352
-157.2  2.4 100088
-147.6  2.4 100088
-123.6  2.4 200176
-318.6  1.2 200176
-315    1.2 200176
-289.8  1.2 200176
-288.6  1.2 200176
-286.2  1.2 400352
-283.8  1.2 200176
-282.6  1.2 400352
-281.4  1.2 200176
-277.8  1.2 200176
-276.6  1.2 400352
-275.4  1.2 200176
-271.8  1.2 200176
-270.6  1.2 200176
-267    1.2 200176
-263.4  1.2 200176
-261    1.2 400352
-258.6  1.2 200176
-256.2  1.2 800704
-255    1.2 200176
-250.2  1.2 400352
-249    1.2 600528
-246.6  1.2 400352
-238.2  1.2 400352
-235.8  1.2 200176
-233.4  1.2 200176
-232.2  1.2 200176
-229.8  1.2 600528
-228.6  1.2 200176
-225    1.2 200176
-223.8  1.2 200176
-222.6  1.2 200176
-220.2  1.2 200176
-219    1.2 200176
-216.6  1.2 200176
-214.2  1.2 3.00264e+006
-211.8  1.2 400352
-210.6  1.2 400352
-205.8  1.2 200176
-204.6  1.2 1.00088e+006
-203.4  1.2 200176
-202.2  1.2 400352
-201    1.2 200176
-199.8  1.2 200176
-196.2  1.2 200176
-195    1.2 200176
-193.8  1.2 200176
-190.2  1.2 600528
-189    1.2 200176
-187.8  1.2 200176
-186.6  1.2 200176
-181.8  1.2 500440
-180.6  1.2 200176
-179.4  1.2 200176
-178.2  1.2 200176
-171    1.2 400352
-169.8  1.2 400352
-168.6  1.2 500440
-161.4  1.2 200176
-132.6  1.2 200176
-125.4  1.2 200176
};
\addplot+[domain=-350:-100,no marks,green,very thick] {30};
\addplot3 coordinates {(-350,40,1e5) (-100,40,1e5)};
\addplot3+[ultra thick,yellow] coordinates {(-350,50,1e5) (-100,50,1e5)};
%\draw [green!70!red,very thick](axis cs:-350,20,1e5) -- (axis cs:-150,20,1e5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image to your question? Then we have an impression what you are talking about without the need of TeXing the document first ...

Comment: done :) @StefanPinnow

Comment: Its a 3D graph and you are looking your values "from the top". Whatever views you use those lines will always be behind the points. You should change your table to fit a 2D plot.

Comment: i understand ... but for me the "behaviour" of latex does not make sense... i dont know how to realise it in a 2d plot because i need the overlapping command point meta=\thisrow{count} to display the points correctly at the moment in my 3d plot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to move the markers to a "lower layer" by adding the lines

```
  set layers=standard,
  mark layer=axis background,
```

to the `axis` environment. This results in ...

[image: image of the code after adding the above two lines]

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue just add `clip mode=individual` as an option of the table.

```
\addplot3+[
    scatter,mark=diamond*,only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{count},
    z buffer=sort  ,
    clip mode=individual
]
table {...
```

[image]